# Calling two Model functions from a single Controller function in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Good afternoon
Guys I am stuck here in a problem and I couldn't resolve it so had to ask here.The problem is that i want to load two functions

```
function FETCH_DATA($HOTEL_ID){
    $this->db->where(['hotel_id' => $HOTEL_ID]);

    $DATA   =   $this->db->get('hotel_tbl');
    return $DATA->result();

}
```

&

```
function FETCH_ASSOCIATION($HOTEL_ID){
    $this->db->where(['hotel_id' => $HOTEL_ID]);

    $ASSOCIATION = $this->db->get('hotel_association');
    return $ASSOCIATION->result();
}
```

from `AdminModel.php` in my `AdminController.php` whose code is as following

```
function DESCRIPTION(){
        $this->load->model('AdminModel');
        $HOTEL_ID   = $this->session->userdata('hotel_id');
        $a['data']  = $this->AdminModel->FETCH_DATA($HOTEL_ID);
        $this->load->view("Description", $a);
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: both methods belongs to which models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass the variables like this,

```
 $a['data1']  = $this->AdminModel->FETCH_DATA($HOTEL_ID);
 $a['data2']  = $this->AdminModel->FETCH_ASSOCIATION($HOTEL_ID);
```

and you are good to go!!

Comment: @NOONE its strange that you have un-accept same answer of JYoThi which is answer earlier than this and accepted this answer

Answer (score 1):

You can call more modal function and send data to view  like below

```
function DESCRIPTION(){
        $this->load->model('AdminModel');
        $HOTEL_ID   = $this->session->userdata('hotel_id');
        $a['data1']  = $this->AdminModel->FETCH_DATA($HOTEL_ID);
        $a['data2']  = $this->AdminModel->FETCH_ASSOCIATION($HOTEL_ID);
        $this->load->view("Description", $a);
}
```